# Как увеличить буквы(не UpperCase) отдельной части в текстовом документе в notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

ну хочу, но не знаю как выделить текст и увеличить выделенный текст в размерах.

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Простой текст не имеет форматирования.